# How to save String format?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I'm working with jsf 1.2 and richFaces 3.3, I need to save a text with the specific format writed by user, including spaces, returns etc...

There is a special tag for do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richfaces has a `<rich:editor>` tag: http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=editor&sample=advancedConfiguration&skin=blueSky

I don't know is it in RichFaces 3.3. If it isn't, you can use `<h:inputTextarea>` with CKEditor.

CKEditor demo: http://ckeditor.com/demo
CKEditor download: http://ckeditor.com/download

The can use the `<h:inputTextarea>` or `<rich:edit>` content as follow: `<h:outputText value="#{someBean.field}" escape="false" />`